# Strange AJAX error in Magento 2.4

Tags: ajax, json, magento24, json-response

I developed a module for Magento 2.4 that consumes an API with multiple endpoints and one of them is returning the response as JSON.

If I create an AJAX call, the response I will get on the desktop version is a valid JSON, but on mobile, the same AJAX call gives an error (SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<').

If I remove "dataType: JSON" and parse the returned AJAX response as a string on mobile, I will see that it contains a short  tag (script ... pub/errors/report.php ... ).

What could be the issue behind this? I can't parse the response on mobile as JSON, but everything works as expected on the desktop version.

Thank you!

Comment: script ... pub/errors/report.php  -> Which means your script throws error and doesn't return the JSON

Comment: According with the API Docs, that endpoint should return a JSON and indeed, it is a JSON. If I pass “dataType: json”, I will see a valid JSON response on desktop, but not on mobile where an error is given. A short-term solution was to remove the dataType line, split the response (which is now available as a string) by “<script” and then parse the first part as a JSON object. That would work both on mobile and desktop, but as I said, it’s strange and I am sure I can find a better solution or the reason behind it.